# Defintion of CRLB for time-dependent R.Vs/Time series

Tags: time-series, estimation, unbiased-estimator

I have been reading about estimating frequency/phase of a sinusoid. The CRLB is mentioned in a number of papers but I don't understand how it applies since each data point isn't from the same random variable.

If your model is $X[n] = sin(\omega T n + \phi)$ and you are seeking the estimate $\omega$ and $\phi$ using sampling, you're not extracting data points from the same distribution each sample.

Can someone explain what is going on?